# Explanation of Eclipse / IntelliJ Android Compiler versus Command Line

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, android-maven-plugin

So I've been encountering a problem trying to move off of the Eclipse and or IntelliJ IDE compilers for Android. Here is a related question with the same problem.

[Android-Maven-Plugin v3.4.0 cannot find drawable resources when building app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248258/android-maven-plugin-v3-4-0-cannot-find-drawable-resources-when-building-app)

I was wondering though if someone could explain the differences of using an IDE to build an Android App versus the command like (Android Maven in this case) and why perhaps the IDE compiler is generous in generating the Android Application while the command like compiler breaks at the smallest warning or error.